# Possible to change function name in definition?

Tags: python, function, attributes

I tried several ways to change the function name in the definition, but they failed.

```
>>> def f():
        pass
>>> f.__name__
'f'
>>> def f():
        f.__name__ = 'new name'
>>> f.__name__
'f'
>>> def f():
        self.__name__ = 'new name'
>>> f.__name__
'f'
```

But I can change the name attribute after defining it.

```
>>> def f():
        pass
>>> f.__name__ = 'new name'
>>> f.__name__
'new name'
```

Any way to change/set it in the definition (other than using a decorator)?

Comment: The reason `self.__method__()` won't work is because `self` is an argument passed to the argument from the interpreter. There is no mechanism passing an instance to your function. (Incidentally, the variable name doesn't have to be `self`, it can be `foo`, or `bar` or whatever)

Comment: Are you writing this code for job security? :)

Comment: This does not answer your question but I think you will find it interesting as it explains some of the "names" that a function is referenced by: https://medium.com/@vadimpushtaev/name-of-python-function-e6d650806c4

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The function body is not executed until you execute the function. You could use a decorator though:

```
def rename(newname):
    def decorator(f):
        f.__name__ = newname
        return f
    return decorator
```

And then use it like this:

```
@rename('new name')
def f():
    pass
print f.__name__
```

However, the function is still only reachable as `f`.

Comment: Hi @ThiefMaster. But how can I change the name of the function and make it be reachable as such?

Answer (score 3):

No. The closest you can come to this is defining a callable class with each instance having its `__name__` set in the initializer.

Answer (score 2):

The function body is not executed until you call the function, so there's no way you can use the function body to alter what happens at definition time.  Why do you want to do this anyway?  If you're writing the function and want it to have a different name, just define it with a different name.

Comment: I originally wanted it because I thought I needed it (making a function that returns a function whose name is based on the outer function's parameters). Then I realized I didn't need to do it within the inner function definition, but was still curious anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in the function body, you're saying that part of the **execution** of `f` is setting its name to `'new name'`. Obviously that's not going to do anything before the function has been called.

Using a decorator **is** the canonical way to declare that a function is a bit different than its `def` block alone would indicate, and you're not going to find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably stupid but kinda works?

```
>>> f = None
>>> def new_name():
    global f
    f = new_name


>>> new_name()
>>> f
<function new_name at 0x01945108>
>>> f.__name__
'new_name'
```

Comment: This is not great indeed.  You are addressing the function by the variable name in which you hope that it is still stored, but by the time you call the function, it may already be stored in some array of functions, and the global variable `f` may be deleted or reused for something else.